# Getting user profile pictures without FQL - graph api v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using FQL to get all the photos in the user profile pictures album.
Since facebook decided to deprecate FQL in their latest version of graph api, im looking for the easiest and fastest way to get the user profile pictures (all of them)

I was using this FQL:
SELECT object_id, src_big, src_big_height FROM photo WHERE aid in (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = 'XXXX' AND type = 'profile') LIMIT 20"

Any graph method that would get me the equivalent in 1 graph call? (I know i call call for /user/albums and to use the album id later to get the photos, but i don't want to seperate it to 2 calls)

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best I could came up was using graph api field expansion:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=albums.limit(1).fields(name,photos.fields(name,picture,source,images))

Im assuming the first album is the profile pictures.

Hope this can help others :)